# check external website registration

Tags: spam

I'm trying to create a PHP based game where you have to do all sorts of simple but un-obvious tasks in order to progress to the next level (eg. refresh browser, press keyboard combination, ...) Kinda like the game "this is the only level" (if anyone has ever heard of it)

Now I was thinking: Would it be possible to create a level where they'd have to sign up at a different page in order to progress to the next level?

So say for example they need to sign up to goal.com and if they're signed up they proceed to the next level. The page would need to constantly check if the signup process on the other site is completed. Is this even possbible? And if so, any thoughts on how?

Thanks!

Comment: Not familiar with the technical details, but you could probably use openid or oauth or something like that and require them to authenticate at the third party site and get a token to come back.  Kind of like Facebook Connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With most sites, given a username and password, you can check if an account exists.

All you have to do is post some data to a url and parse the output for a successful login.

You may have problems with the bigger sites since they have other checks in place to deter scripted logins.